# StaleElementReferenceExcpetion While paginating selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Please see the below image
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3trUH.png) 
`

```
List<WebElement> countOfPagination = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='paginate_button ']"));
    if(countOfPagination.size()>0)
            {
    for(int i=0;i<countOfPagination.size();i++)
    {
        
        String xpath = "//a[@class='paginate_button '][" + (i+1) +"]";
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)));
        element.click();
        System.out.println("Clicked on "+element.getText());
    }
            }
```

While executing i was getting g/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid exception.

You are trying to print the `text of the page` that is page number after you click on that page. After you have clicked the WebElement `element` a new page is opened and the old xpath is no longer valid.

[Link to refer](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/stale-element-reference-exception-selenium-webdriver/)

And no need to start the iteration from 0 because its already in page 1.

Try like below.

**1: Print the page based on the iteration.**

```
List<WebElement> countpage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='paginate_button ']"));
if(countpage.size()>0) {
    for (int i = 1; i<countpage.size(); i++) {
        String xpath = "//a[@class='paginate_button ']["+(i+1)+"]";
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        element.click();
        System.out.println("Clicked on" + i);
                
    }
}
```

**2: Redefine the `WebElement` and then try to print the page number that was clicked on.**

```
List<WebElement> countpage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='paginate_button ']"));
if(countpage.size()>0) {
    for (int i = 1; i<countpage.size(); i++) {
        String xpath = "//a[@class='paginate_button ']["+(i+1)+"]";
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        element.click();
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        System.out.println("Clicked on " + element1.getText());
                
    }
}
```

**Output for both**

```
Clicked on 2
Clicked on 3
Clicked on 4
Clicked on 5
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, accept the same. Click on the write mark option available at the left side of the answer.